# Does message_queue guarantee the order of the messages?

Tags: c++, boost, boost-interprocess

In the official document
[Synchronization mechanisms - 1.77.0](https://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_77_0/doc/html/interprocess/synchronization_mechanisms.html#interprocess.synchronization_mechanisms.message_queue), it says

> Each message can have also a priority so that higher priority messages are read before lower priority messages.

But what about the messages that have the same priority? Can we safely assume the messages that have same priority are FIFO in a `message_queue`? Thanks.

Comment: I do not see that in the docs.  You could check the source, but if it isn't in the docs, it could change next or previous version...